# gradle Coordinates for android Youtube Client

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have successfully managed to use the `YouTubePlayerFragment` for android by downloading it from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/
 and then adding the `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar` to VCS.

However, I cant find this library's maven/gradle coordinates. Does anyone know where i can find this library as a proper gradle dependency?

Comment: Someone posted similar question on Google, but no response from Google yet. [YouTube APIs should have support via gradle & documentation should be updated](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7048)

Comment: ok thanks for response. Lets hope google fixes it :)